# Hibernate5 with wildfly8 (and jboss-logging)

Tags: wildfly, wildfly-8, hibernate-5.x, jboss-logging

My Problem:
Hibernate-5.0.12-Final uses `Jboss-Logging-3.3.1.Final` but wildfly8 supplies `jboss-logging-3.1.4.GA`. Using `3.1.4.GA` with `Hibernate5` leads to a `NoSuchMethodException`.

I'm deploying a `war` including `Hibernate-5.0.12-Final` *AND* `Jboss-Logging-3.3.1.Final` into a wildfly8 AS.

I tried the following:

1. By adding the `add-logging-api-dependencies` in the `standalone.xml`

   ```
    <add-logging-api-dependencies value="false"/>
    <use-deployment-logging-config value="false"/>
   ```
2. Excluding the logging subsystem or just the `org.jboss.logging` dependency in the `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` which I placed in the `WEB-INF` of the .war-file that is deployed into the wildfly AS.

   ```
   <jboss-deployment-structure>
   <deployment>
       <exclusions>
           <module name="org.jboss.logging" />
       </exclusions>
   </deployment>
   </jboss-deployment-structure>
   ```

   or

   ```
   <jboss-deployment-structure>
   <deployment>
      <exclude-subsystems>
         <subsystem name="logging" />
     </exclude-subsystems>
   </deployment>
   </jboss-deployment-structure>
   ```

Both did NOT work. It worked as there was no more logging from my application, *BUT* the provided `Jboss-Logging-3.3.1.Final` wasnt not used.

So I ended up to updating the `jar` of jboss-logging in the wildfly-modules folder (`modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/logging/`). This worked, but I think there must be a nicer solution, as exchanging/replacing the `jar` can break dependencies of other modules that require jboss-logging in a certain version (3.1.4.GA).

**TLDR;** I just want to tell my wildfly8 that it should use the jboss-logging jar (provided by me, in the war file) instead of the jboss-logging.jar provided by the wildfly AS.

Comment: With the `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` were you still seeing the `NoSuchMethodException`? Really the best solution would be to upgrade to WildFly 10.1.0.Final if you want Hibernate 5.x.

Comment: No I no longer saw the exception, as there was absolutely no logging output from my deployed application. Switching to wildfly10 is currently no option.

Comment: Not seeing log output likely just means you don't have a log manager configured. Are you including logback or log4j in your deployment? Is there a reason you need Hibernate 5, but can't upgrade WildFly itself?